# Multiple Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-instances, shortcut

I am using the following code to try and get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to press a toolstrip button:

```
 Private Sub take_register_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S And Keys.Control Then
        ToolStripButton20.PerformClick()

    End If

End Sub
```

I am a newbie at this, so I dont understand millions of lines of coding, so can you please keep it as simple as possible :-) .

Comment: Did you know you can simply assign a shortcut key combo in the designer?  Otherwise, what is the question?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Total guesswork here since there is no actual question.  First, in order to get something like that work, you need to set `KeyPreview = True` for the form.  Next, you probably want to use the `KeyDown` event instead of `KeyPress`:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(...)
    ' when possible use AndAlso for speed and to avoid some errors in
    ' some situations.  if e.Control is False, the second part wont be evaluated.
    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then

        ToolStripButton20.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

To repeat: you can simply assign a shortcut key combo to the menu object in the designer and let .NET do all the work.  ...and I don't know where "multiple" comes in to play unless <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> counts as multiple somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still dosent do anything. Any other solutions do you think?

Comment: is there code in the `ToolStripButton20` click event??  what is it supposed to do? The REAL code will need stuff in place of the `...` like in your code block.  Place the cursor on `ToolStripButton20.PerformClick()` and press F9, run the program and see if it stops when you press Ctrl+S.

Comment: For the coding on the click event, I have: a lot of coding except it is not letting me insert it all. When I press F9, it is coming up with a red line for the toolstripbutton20

Comment: The red line is a breakpoint, one of the most powerful tools in VS.  The code will stop executing when it gets there.  There are 2 pieces: is the Shortcut Key trap firing and b) if so maybe the menuitem click is written wrong.  You should be able to edit your own question to add important details like what is in the click event.