# Detect when some key press and release

Tags: vb.net

I'm having difficulty looking for a way to do it

I want my application do something when key press. For example, when user press F1 then it will sendkeys F1 as long as F1 still press and when user release F1 it won't sendkeys F1.

Couldn't find a way to detect when the user release the key

And how to automatically detect the key press and sendkeys according to the keypress??

thanks for anyhelp

Comment: There's no point to that, the F1 key already works that way.

Comment: what I mean was when I press for example `e` it will do F1 until `e` release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do it

here I will post the code so if somebody looking for it, this is the answer

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System

Public Class Form1
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Keys) As Integer

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SendInput(ByVal nInputs As Integer, ByRef pInputs As NativeMethods.INPUT, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "User32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up

Private Sub DoKeyBoard(ByVal flags As NativeMethods.KEYEVENTF, ByVal key As Keys)
    Dim input As NativeMethods.INPUT
    Dim ki As NativeMethods.KEYBDINPUT
    input.type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard
    input.u.ki = ki
    input.u.ki.wVk = Convert.ToInt16(key)
    input.u.ki.wScan = 0
    input.u.ki.time = 0
    input.u.ki.dwFlags = flags
    input.u.ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim cbSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(NativeMethods.INPUT))
    Dim result As Integer = NativeMethods.SendInput(1, input, cbSize)
    If result = 0 Then Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error)
End Sub

Private WithEvents myKeyboardHookManager As KeyboardHookListener
Dim hookEnabled As Boolean
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    myKeyboardHookManager = New KeyboardHookListener(New GlobalHooker())
    myKeyboardHookManager.
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to get something like that work, you need to set `KeyPreview = True` for the form. Next, you probably want to use the KeyDown event.  Trap for whatever key (`Keys.F1`) and as long as the key is down you will get keydown events to spam F1.

We are having a special on keyboard traps today.    [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19366782/1070452) as well.  Beyond that you will have to try some of this yourself.  Thats how you learn.  When you get stuck, post your code.

You could also search the 60,059 questions here tagged VB NET/6 to find samples.

Comment: sir I have found a way...but it still not working like I want..could you help me??